# Error when building kernel module using dkms

Tags: kernel-modules, dkms

I have a notebook running Kubuntu 22.04.2 LTS with a rtl8852be network card. I installed the source of the driver in `/usr/src/rtl8852be-5.15` and added the following `dkms.conf` file to the directory:

```
PACKAGE_VERSION=5.15
#MAKE="make -j8 -C $kernel_source_dir M=\$(pwd)"i
MAKE="'make' -C $kernel_source_dir M=\$(pwd)"
CLEAN="'make' clean"
BUILT_MODULE_NAME="8852be"
#BUILT_MODULE_LOCATION=.
DEST_MODULE_NAME="rtl8852be"
DEST_MODULE_LOCATION="/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/"
AUTOINSTALL=yes
```

I can install the driver fine using `make && make install` while the current directory is `/usr/src/rtl8852be-5.15`

But when I run `dkms autoinstall` I get the following error:

```
root@laptop:/usr/src/rtl8852be-5.15# dkms autoinstall

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel. Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
Current directory: /var/lib/dkms/rtl8852be/5.15/build
'make' -C /lib/modules/5.15.0-70-generic/build M=/usr/src/rtl8852be-5.15...
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8852be: 5.15 not found
Error!  Build of 8852be.ko failed for: 5.15.0-70-generic (x86_64)
Make sure the name of the generated module is correct and at the root of the
build directory, or consult make.log in the build directory
/var/lib/dkms/rtl8852be/5.15/build/ for more information.
```

The line starting with 'Current directory:' has been inserted by me into dkms. It shows that make is not running from within the source directory. Not sure why or where to fix this.

Here are the contents of `make.log`:

```
DKMS make.log for rtl8852be-5.15 for kernel 5.15.0-70-generic (x86_64)
Mi 19. Apr 16:07:47 CEST 2023
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-70-generic'
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-70-generic'
```

Does anyone have any idea what to look for?